# Не могу понять,как изменить свойство

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

пишу бота ВК. Я сделал проверку, где проверяется,хочет ли человек начать мини игру угадай число

```
self._ANSWERS = ['ДА', 'НЕТ']

if message.upper() == self._ANSWERS[0]:
            return "Здорово! Вводи номер  от 1 до 150, если угадаешь, я тебе напишу об этом! (всего два числа)"
```

Мне нужно сделать так,что бы если человек отвечает "да"(хочет сыграть в мини игру), на не правильный ответ ему писало бы "не отгадал",если он отказывается

```
if message.upper() == self._ANSWERS[1]:
            return "Жаль, можешь воспользоваться другими функциями бота: 'Команды'"
```

То на слово,которое не бот знает писало "Прости, я тебя не понимаю"

Я пытался:
В конструкторе класса создал свойство self._ANS = False

```
class VkBot:
    def __init__(self, user_id):  
        #часть вырезана,она не нужна
        print('')
        self._ANSWERS = ['ДА', 'НЕТ']
        self._COMMANDS = ["ПРИВЕТ", "ВРЕМЯ", "ПОКА", "ИГРА", "ТОП", "АДМИН","КОМАНДЫ", 'ЗАКОНЧИТЬ']
        self._ANS = False
```

И в программе менял значения с False на True
Далее создавал проверку, если self._ANS = True - отвечать "Не отгадал"
Если на оборот - "Я тебя не понимаю"

Если Вы меня как-то не поняли, то можете объяснить как менять значения свойства в классе? (прикреплю весь код)

```
import vk_api
import bs4
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll
import requests
import time
from random import randint

class VkBot:
    def __init__(self, user_id):  
        print('')
        self._USER_ID = user_id
        self._USER_LINK = "https://vk.com/id"+str(user_id)
        self._USERNAME = self._get_user_name_from_vk_id(user_id)
        self._ANSWERS = ['ДА', 'НЕТ']
        self._COMMANDS = ["ПРИВЕТ", "ВРЕМЯ", "ПОКА", "АВОКАДО", "ТОП", "АДМИН","КОМАНДЫ", 'ЗАКОНЧИТЬ']
        self._NUMBER = ["71","59"]
        self._ANS = False

    def stat(self, yes):
        _YES = self.yes
        
    def _get_user_name_from_vk_id(self, user_id):
        request = requests.get("https://vk.com/id"+str(user_id))
        bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
        user_name = self._clean_all_tag_from_str(bs.findAll("title")[0])
        return user_name.split()[0]
        
    def _get_time(self):
        request = requests.get("https://my-calend.ru/date-and-time-today")
        b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
        return self._clean_all_tag_from_str(str(b.select(".page")[0].findAll("h2")[1])).split()[1]
        
       
    @staticmethod
    def _clean_all_tag_from_str(string_line):
        result = ""
        not_skip = True
        for i in list(string_line):
            if not_skip:
                if i == "<":
                    not_skip = False
                else:
                    result += i
            else:
                if i == ">":
                    not_skip = True
        
        return result
        
    def new_message(self, message):
        if message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[0]:
            return f"Привет-привет, {self._USERNAME}!"
        elif message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[1]:
            return self._get_time()    
        elif message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[2]:
            return "Пока-пока!"
        elif message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[4]:
            return "Топ по количеству найденых авокадиков:\n1. Игнат Борисов - 1 отгаданное авокадо"
        elif message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[5]:
            if self._USER_ID ==  454267478:
                return f"Количество найденных авокадо за ссесию:{self._AVOKADO}"
            else:
                return "Нет доступа!"
        elif message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[6]:
            return "Все команды бота:\n1. Время - покажет московское время\n2. Авокадо - начать игру 'Авокадо'\n3. Топ - показывает топ пользователя по количеству найденных авокадо(на данный момент обновляется в ручную)\n4. Админ - функция для администраторов,на данный момент показывает только статистику"
        if message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[3]:
            return "Привет,хочешь отгадать авокадо?"
        if message.upper() == self._ANSWERS[0]:
            return "Здорово! Вводи номер авокадо  от 1 до 150, если угадаешь, я тебе напишу об этом! (всего два числа)"
        if message.upper() == self._ANSWERS[1] or message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[7]:
            return "Жаль, можешь воспользоваться другими функциями бота: 'Команды'"
        if message.upper() == self._NUMBER[0] or message.upper() == self._NUMBER[1]:
            print(f'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\nВНИМАНИЕ: {self._USERNAME}, {self._USER_LINK}: Нашел авокадо!')
            return "Крутоооооооооо!!! Ты отгадал АВОКАДО"
        if message.upper() != self._NUMBER[0] and self._YES == True or message.upper() != self._NUMBER[1] and self._YES == True:
            return "Не отгадал!"
        else:
            return f"{self._USERNAME}, я тебя не понимаю :("
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ:
Нужно создавать переменную отдельно от класса, объявив ее глобальной
Далее, в методе отправки сообщения так-же обновить ее глобальной

```
global _ANS
_ANS = False
```

```
def new_message(self, message):
        if message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[0]:
            global _ANS
            return f"Привет-привет, {self._USERNAME}!"
```